# When can IExceptionHandlerPathFeature be null with ExceptionHandlerMiddleware in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core, .net-core

Microsoft provides this example for the `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-custom-exception-handling-code). This is an excerpt:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        ...

        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("File error thrown!");
        }

        ...
    });
});
```

I cannot quite understand why would they use `?.` operator to get the exception? Can this delegate be triggered without `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature`? It does not seem logical to have an exception handler without a guaranteed access to exception.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/28157e62597bf0e043bc7e937e44c5ec81946b83/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L78) is the code and it does not seem possible to have null in there.

Comment: if `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature` implementation unable to find for some readon then it could be `null`

Comment: It can kind of be theoretically possible, but it's just POCO in [practice](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/28157e62597bf0e043bc7e937e44c5ec81946b83/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerFeature.cs#L10)

Comment: It's not the error that could be null but the `exceptionHandlerPathFeature`, if it's not found in the `context.Features` collection

Comment: yes, and it can be `null` as per what i see, but i don't exactly know the cases at the moment.

Comment: In normal scenarios, it will never be null. However, you can implement `IWebHost` *very* simplistically and it would be. The default implementation will have this feature, but that doesn't mean all implementations will. Outside of that, it's just good practice to always code around nulls. Maybe it never will be null, but there's a *potential* for null, so that case is covered. This is perhaps especially important for an exception handler as you can end up in an endless loop from the handler throwing exceptions itself.

Comment: Yes, I have written a bit wrong question i see :) Shall fix. Now why would we have an exception handler that does not guarantee a way to get access to exception? Isn't that strange?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Can't quite agree that it's a general good practice to always code against null, since in my opinion is defensive programming and I'd rather see an exception than have a completely unexpected null. Fortunately it'll be a bit better with next C# when null's won't be allowed, though it's another discussion for another day :)

Comment: Actually the strict null checking in C# 8.0 is opt-in. It is defensive coding, but that's kind of the point. I'm not sure what you mean by "unexpected nulls" because when you add null gaurding, no null is "unexpected" at that point. Exceptions is by far the *worst* strategy, especially since `NullReferenceExceptions` are exclusively runtime exceptions. In general relying on exceptions is bad, and runtime exceptions should be avoid entirely.

Comment: i had ExceptionDetails is null  in the following code :  var ExceptionDetails = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

Answer (score 3):

In my particular situation, I had a custom error controller with one of the actions:

```
[Route("Error")]
public IActionResult Error(ErrorViewModel model)
{
    var exceptionDetails = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    model.Code = 500;

    _logger.Error($"The path {exceptionDetails?.Path} threw an exception " +
         $"{exceptionDetails?.Error}");

    return View(nameof(Error), model);
}
```

`IExceptionHandlerPathFeature` was null whenever user enters my error page route in the browser mechanically by hand. So I had to put null conditional operator to restrict null reference exception.